# How can the HTML <dialog> element be positioned according to normal flow when opened with showModal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dialog, modal-dialog

When using a `<dialog>` element with `.show()` it is positioned according to normal `position` etc. CSS properties.

Is it possible to have that same positioning with `.showModal()`?

Even when using

```css
dialog:modal {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

to override the browsers `position: fixed` the dialog ends up in the top left corner (checked with chromium and firefox).

EDIT: copying my comment here for better visibility and avoid more answers about CSS tweaking:

> I know how to do computations and move the thing around with `top` and `left`. But this is what I would like to avoid.

Meaning I would like to just rip it out of the hands which hold it back as if position:fixed.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const b2 = document.getElementById('b2');
const dialog = document.getElementById('dialog');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {dialog.showModal();});
b2.addEventListener('click', () => {dialog.show();});
dialog.addEventListener('click', () => {dialog.close();});
```

```css
#dialog:modal, #dialog {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#wrapper {
  background: #fafafa;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">open modal</button>
<button id="b2">just show</button>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>Some context below which the dialog should appear.</div>
  <dialog id="dialog">click to close</dialog>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need it to take up space in the layout?

Comment: I think I  can deal with anything that shows how to rip it out of the hands which hold it back as if `position:fixed`. Ultimately I don't want it to take space, but overlay the page like modal, just at the "right" position. I think I know how to do computations and move the thing around with top and left. But this is what I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

I hope you find a CSS-only solution, but if you put the dialog in a wrapper div, you can use that div's position to absolutely position the dialog when you show it:

```css
#dialog {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="dialog-wrapper">
    <dialog id="dialog">click to close</dialog>
</div>
```

```js
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const wrapper = document.getElementById("dialog-wrapper");
    dialog.style.left = wrapper.offsetLeft + "px";
    dialog.style.top = wrapper.offsetTop + "px";
    dialog.showModal();
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const b2 = document.getElementById("b2");
const dialog = document.getElementById("dialog");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const wrapper = document.getElementById("dialog-wrapper");
    dialog.style.left = wrapper.offsetLeft + "px";
    dialog.style.top = wrapper.offsetTop + "px";
    dialog.showModal();
});
b2.addEventListener("click", () => {
    dialog.show();
});
dialog.addEventListener("click", () => {
    dialog.close();
});
```

```css
#dialog {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">open modal</button>
<button id="b2">just show</button>
<div>
    <div>Some context below which the dialog should appear.</div>
    <div id="dialog-wrapper">
        <dialog id="dialog">click to close</dialog>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it was that manual positioning that I tried to avoid, but it is probably the easiest without losing other benefits of modal. I guess the `top layer` verbiage found in https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#dom-dialog-showmodal has something to do with it. Where the `top layer` linked there says things like *If its position property computes to fixed, its containing block is the viewport, and the initial containing block otherwise.* and for the last two I can't even tell the difference.:-/

Comment: Depending on use case, when scrolling is involved the positions need adjustment. In my use case I just `close()` the dialog when the user starts scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `margin-right: 0;`, and set `width` and `height` as needed. It worked for me ! No need for `position`: it is set to fixed. The dialog is then anchored to the right of the window.

Answer (score 1):

*edited 04.03.24; thanks to [JGC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925255/how-can-the-html-dialog-element-be-positioned-according-to-normal-flow-when-op/77652902?noredirect=1#comment137640638_77652902)*

### Answer

Since the `<dialog>` element is in it's own *layer* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41816764/13929165) for more information) in relation to the rest of the DOM, it isn't possible to set it as inline, which I understood to be the question.

### Positioning `<dialog>` in general

Also leaving this here for anyone searching for how to position dialogs: [SebastianZ mentions in this comment](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/4645#issuecomment-1676075036), that the dialog is centered using `margin: auto` by default. Deactivating margins therefore allows positioning the dialog using absolute coordinates i. e. with `top` and `left`.

*Example of a centered top dialog:*

```css
dialog {
 margin: 0; /* `margin: auto;` is the default. */
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<dialog open>
Foo
</dialog>
```

or, if you don't need full control and just want to center the modal at the top of the page:

```css
dialog {
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<dialog open>
Foo
</dialog>
```

Comment: SebastianZ's comment is correct, but I found it quite misleading. In Safari at least, I can only set it to 0 or I can't set it.
Better to say "setting `margin: 0;` means that instead of the dialog's origin being in the center of the window, it is then at top left. This allows `top:` and `left:` values to be set as expected.