# place an element above the #top-layer

Tags: html, css

I created a dev tool and used z-index to be above all other elements:

```css
.devTool {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

Unfortunately this breaks once a modal `<dialog />` elements is opened in `modal` mode.

The user is no longer able to interact with the `.devTool`.

The reason is the new `#top-layer` concept which is ontop of all elements:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/what-is-the-top-layer/

Is there any way to ensure my devTool is always on top of all elements (even if those are modal dialogs) and stay interactive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to position a div on top of a <dialog> tag that is not its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41815069/is-it-possible-to-position-a-div-on-top-of-a-dialog-tag-that-is-not-its-parent)

Comment: No - I am searching for a way to be always the top #top-layer without disabling interactivity for other elements

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it is not possible. From [the W3C specs draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-4/#document-top-layer):

> NOTE: The top layer is managed entirely by the user agent; it cannot be directly manipulated by authors.

The only way seems to use an element that renders in the top layer... Maybe `.devTools` can be itself wrapped in a `<dialog>` placed as the last element? From the same specs:

> Top layer elements are rendered in the order they appear in the top layer; the last element in the top layer is rendered on top of everything else.

Also keep in mind that your solution could fail for another reason: the `z-index` value is relative to the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_positioned_layout/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context), so a lesser z-index value in a higher stacking context could end up on top of your element.

Comment: that's so sad.. sounds like browser vendors pushing features without talking to the web devs

zIndex works very well here - add an overlay to the body element give it a high z-index, pointer-events:none and it will always be on top

Comment: @jantimon Yes, it is said. It means I can not use <dialog> for things like error information. (Since I can not override it with an update dialog for a PWA.)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put .divTool above the dialog you can just make another dialog and put the .divTool element in it then adjust the code to open the second dialog whenever the first dialog opened, this would make the last opened dialog would be above all elements.
see this article to know more about dialog and top-layer
[Top Layer vs Z-Index for Frontend UI Dialogs](https://blog.bitsrc.io/top-layer-vs-z-index-for-frontend-dialogs-fcb12217a834)

Answer (score 0):

You can un-modal the `<dialog>` by using `.show()` instead of `.showModal()`, after which it will follow regular stacking rules and `z-index` will work again.